# IS NOT DISTINCT FROM versus =

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.1

Can anyone please help me. I have the following postgresql query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM trackPointsA 
WHERE gid NOT IN (
SELECT a.gid 
FROM trackPointsA a, trackPointsB b 
WHERE a.the_geom = b.the_geom
AND b.datetime = a.time::timestamp with time zone 
GROUP BY a.gid ORDER BY a.gid
)
```

This query yields 0 which is correct. However, if I replace `b.datetime = a.time::timestamp with time zone` with `b.datetime IS NOT DISTINCT FROM a.time::timestamp with time zone` then it no longer yields 0. Why is this? I need to use the `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` version since I sometimes have null values which want to treat as distinct values.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

`a is not distinct from b` amounts to writing:

```
a = b or a is null and b is null
```

Presumably, you've rows where b.datetime and a.time are both null.

(I'd add a note on index usage. This might have changed since I last checked, but back in the 9.1 days, is distinct from wasn't expanded, but rather treated as an operator in its own right. This prevented it from using indexes entirely.)

Comment: None of these fields are null. So it should work the same right?

Comment: Try to identify the offending rows, e.g. `select * from ... where b.datetime is not distinct from a.time::timestamp with time zone and not((b.datetime = a.time::timestamp with time zone) is true)`

Comment: @robert: the comment _None of these fields are null_ seems to contradict the question's _I sometimes have null values_

Comment: @DanielVérité: Sorry, I meant in this specific case the offending rows do not have null values. Generally, however, I may have null values.